# Garb just stopped working in Rails 3 without being touched

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I have a Garb model:

```
class Visits

  extend Garb::Model

  metrics :visits, :new_visits, :pageviews
  dimensions :month, :hostname, :network_domain, :country, :region, :source

end
```

And I have this line in my controller:

```
for visit in Visits.results(profile, :start_date => (Date.today-numdays), :filters => { :hostname.eql => "#{@brand.subdomain}.mysite.com" })
```

This has worked fabulously. But all of a sudden, even though none of the actual code has been modified:

```
NoMethodError in AnalyticsController#index
undefined method `eql' for :hostname:Symbol
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install right_http_connection-1.3.0 gem? It will cause the garb/lib/support.rb not to be loaded if you require 'right_http_connection' before 'garb'. If that you could fix this by installing a lower right_http_connection, such as right_http_connection-1.2.4.

After all you can use command

```
 find /Your/gems/installed/dir -name "*.rb" -print | xargs grep '\<support\>' | grep  'require'
```

to find what files cause your garb/lib/support.rb was not loaded anymore.
This link http://kayakjang.github.com/2011/05/27/garb.html may be helpful to you for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the garb/lib/support.rb is not loaded anymore. Did you put `:require => false` to the garb gem line in Gemfile?

Comment: No, it's just "gem 'garb'", could there be some kind of a namespace clash somewhere?

Comment: Maybe there's some other gem, which modifies Symbol. Mongoid does that, for instance.

Comment: What does (:foo.methods - Class.methods) return?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by cutting and pasting the contents of garb/lib/support.rb into the environment.rb file. Not ideal, I know. But I don't know what gem update modified Symbol, and this works. Props to Roman for pointing me in the right direction.